# Show all posts and display comments only if have replies with one or more likes

Tags: laravel

Post model

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'post_id');
}
```

Comment model

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Post');
}

public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Reply', 'comment_id');
}
```

Reply model

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Comment');
}
```

My function

```
App\Post::with('comments.replies')->whereHas('comments.replies', function($query) {
    $query->where('likes', '>', 0);
})->get();
```

I want to show ALL POSTS, and add comments if one or more replie has like
But if there is no any likes on reply, my post wont show.

Comment: Is 'likes' a field on replies table or a different table - relationship with replies?

Comment: Yup, like is field on replies.

Comment: Here is solution. return App\Post::with(['comments' => function($q){
    $q->with('replies')->whereHas('replies', function($q) {
        $q->where('likes', '>', 0);
    });
}])->get();